# Invalid hook call causing page crash

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am bit new to react and using 'react-sticky-table' in functional component. All seemed fine and was working as expected. But now suddenly page crashes saying.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Below is my code.

```
     class Form extends Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {}
        }

        render() {                        
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
                            <StickyTable>
                                <Row>
                                    <Cell>Header 1</Cell>
                                    <Cell>Header 2</Cell>
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <Cell>Cell 1</Cell>
                                    <Cell>Cell 2</Cell>
                                </Row>
                            </StickyTable>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
    }
}
    
    export default connect(
        (storeState) => ({
            result: storeState.result,
        }),
        {
            resetSubmit,        
        }
    )(Form);
```

So here just having StickyTable causes the page to crash.
Note: I have truncated the code for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: React hooks are only valid in functional components, you've shared a class-based component. Where is the hook used?

Comment: It seems to me like version issue. example here uses a class based component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry about that I am still new to these concepts. I haven't used hooks but i suppose its used within the component I am using ? i.e. StickyTable. Because commenting the StickyTable doesn't result in this error and there is no page crash.

Comment: @bron10 Yes exactly same code used to work till last night. Any idea how would i proceed with this?

Comment: Agree with @bron10 since a hook isn't being used in your code that it is likely multiple instances of React.

Comment: @AnonymousCoder what is your react version ?

Comment: It's  "react": "^16.13.1"

Comment: Your code is working fine, with `"react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-sticky-table": "^5.1.4"` not able to reproduce it.. can you confirm your versions with this one ?

Comment: Wow. That's really strange. That's exactly the same as yours :|

Comment: Ok this is weird but now I just gave a try restarting the VS code and now it works. It's weird behavior though. @bron10 Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help :)